# Retrofit 2 - Getting 200 response but not getting data returned

Tags: android, retrofit2

## TL;DR

---

New to retrofit so it's probably a noob mistake. Endpoint works fine in postman and I get `Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=http://192.168.1.249/api/v1/user/1}` in the response but no data related to the user.

## The Problem

---

I have built a REST API using Laravel that I want to access from devices. There will be many endpoints that need to be accessed but I can't get any of them to work. I am trying to get one working before adding the rest, but even though I get a 200 I am getting no data.

All of the properties are present on the response.body but they are all null.

## The Code

---

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.x.tools.actualrest.rest.User;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private CdenApi cdenAPI;

    private String token;

    String requested_with = "XMLHttpRequest";
    String content_type = "application/json";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        createCdenAPI();

        cdenAPI.getUser(requested_with, content_type, "1").enqueue(userCallback);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    private void createCdenAPI() {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                .create();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(CdenApi.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();

        cdenAPI = retrofit.create(CdenApi.class);
    }

    Callback<User> userCallback = new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                User data = new User();
                data = response.body();
            } else {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    };
}
```

CdenApi.java

```
import com.x.tools.actualrest.rest.User;

import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Header;
import retrofit2.http.Path;
import retrofit2.Call;

public interface CdenApi {

    String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.1.249/api/v1/";

    @GET("user/{id}")
    Call<User> getUser(@Header("X-Requested-With") String req_with, @Header("Content-Type") String cont_type, @Path("id")String userId);

}
```

User.java

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class User {

    @SerializedName("id")
    public Integer id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    public String name;
    @SerializedName("email")
    public String email;
    @SerializedName("access_level")
    public Integer accessLevel;
    @SerializedName("created_at")
    public String createdAt;
    @SerializedName("updated_at")
    public String updatedAt;
    @SerializedName("view_boxes")
    public ViewBoxes viewBoxes;

}
```

UserResult.java

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class UserResult {

    @SerializedName("msg")
    public String msg;
    @SerializedName("user")
    public User user;

}
```

ViewBoxes.java

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class ViewBoxes {

    @SerializedName("href")
    public String href;
    @SerializedName("method")
    public String method;

}
```

JSON from endpoint:

```
{
    "msg": "User information",
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Guy",
        "email": "guy@ganker.com",
        "access_level": 1,
        "created_at": "2017-08-22 15:53:06",
        "updated_at": "2017-08-22 15:53:06",
        "view_boxes": {
            "href": "api/v1/user/1",
            "method": "GET"
        }
    }
}
```

## The Solution

---

I need to know where I am going wrong. I am new to retrofit so I'm sure I have implemented something wrong but I can't see the issue.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is user callback beign called? are you getting any error in the stack trace?
do you have internet permission in your manifest?

Comment: It is being called, and no I'm not getting any errors

Comment: You could put a "breakpoint"  ( https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html#breakPoints ) to see what's happening or you could print a log, check that it's not going to the else condition that's empty.

Comment: Also now that I see it, after you set data, it's doing nothing, what are you trying to do with the response?

Comment: I am trying to build a user of type User from the response. Currently I'm just using the debugger to check the value of the response inside the onResponse block. It is being called and like I said I am getting a 200 response with the right url, but the properties on User data are all null

Comment: Nevermind I see what's the problem, you have this:  Call<User>, but the response is not an user is a UserResult, you should have this: Call<UserResult>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you have `Call<User>`, but as for your json you are getting UserResult in the response from the server, so instead it must be `Call<UserResult>` and in userCallback the same, instead of

```
Callback<User> userCallback = new Callback<User>
```

it must be

```
Callback<UserResult> userCallback = new Callback<UserResult>
```

and the same in the onresponse

```
public void onResponse(Call<UserResult> call, Response<UserResult> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                User data = new User();
                data = response.body().user;
            } else {

            }
        }
```

Comment: This looks correct. It is therefore unfortunate that Retrofit2 does not send any form of debug information or log messages when it fails to convert json to java. VERY unfortunate. It becomes a timethief for first time users, just the opposite result of the goal of Retrofit2

Comment: Please go through my question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55467538/retrofit-2-0-getting-response-code-200-but-not-getting-the-desired-data/55468249?noredirect=1#comment97648003_55468249

Comment: "new User()" is not necessary

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    createCdenAPI();
    Response<User> response = cdenAPI.getUser(requested_with, content_type, "1").execute();

    User user = response.body();
 }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with threading to implement this. Which class should implement runnable?

Comment: I don't think you need to use Runnable if you are using retrofit.

Answer (score 0):

In your `MainActivity.java`

remove

```
User data = new User();
data = response.body();
```

and replace it with

```
User data = response.body();
```

Answer (score 0):

Concerning model classes, you can try to use the same model classes for the
network, view and database access, but each has some quirks so it is better to have a generic model class that the db and network models can be converted to/from.

Concerning room and retrofit. Room seems to dislike lists of children and if retrofit gets a 200 (success) error code but no data, issue is probably
that conversion process has failed and retrofit will not give you any info.

Try re-generating netwotrk model classes directly from json and use those.
Android Studio plugin JsonToKotlinClass to create data classes ALT-K or right click
package -> New -> Kotlin data class from JSON

Comment: See full example here:                                                                                                                 
        https://github.com/pstorli/BestMovieDB                                                                    
        https://sites.google.com/site/storlidesignsllc/apps/bestmoviedb

Answer (score -1):

```
        @GET("/users")
        Call<ResponseBody> listRepos();//function to call api
    }

    RetrofitService service = retrofit.create(RetrofitService.class);
    Call<ResponseBody> result = service.listRepos(username);
    result.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        try {
            System.out.println(response.body().string());//convert reponse to string
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

Comment: You should put some explanation with your code, and having 2 answers here with just some code, does not make a lot of sense to me either.

Answer (score -2):

```
response.body().string();

//you get this 

  {
    "msg": "User information",
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Guy",
        "email": "guy@ganker.com",
        "access_level": 1,
        "created_at": "2017-08-22 15:53:06",
        "updated_at": "2017-08-22 15:53:06",
        "view_boxes": {
            "href": "api/v1/user/1",
            "method": "GET"
        }
    }


//instead of this
 
Response{protocol=http/1.1,
 code=200, 
message=OK, 
url=http://192.168.1.249/api/v1/user/1}
```

Comment: This is not relevant in the context of retrofit

Comment: @francisduvivier check this  https://stackoverflow.com/a/63700638/13468014