# Retrofit 2.0: getting response code 200 but not getting the desired data

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

A very disappointing feature of Retrofit 2.0 is that it does not exactly tell where it fails in parsing the response. Hence, In postman when I hit the request with same body, I get a login response as:

```
 {
    "result": "success",
    "response_code": 200,
    "data": {
        "id": "1",
        "display_name": "admin",
        "email": "payal@teckmovers.com",
        "username": "admin",
        "access_token": "8daa8e02ca432e51ae90912fbf63eeea"
    }
}
```

But when I hit the exact same request with exactly the same body in Retrofit, I get a very peculiar response as: {protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=http://192.168.0.52/evidya/wp-api/v1/user/login}. Now I have gone through other related questions with above mentioned problem but none of them is working for me. Please Help. My code:

Retrofit API interface:

```
public interface eVidyaApi {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("user/login")
    Call<LoginResponse> loginUser(
            @HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers,
            @Field("email") String email,
            @Field("password") String password
    );
}
```

Login Function:

```
    public void login() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Login");
        if (!validate()) {
            onLoginFailed();
            return;
        }

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this, R.style.MyDialogTheme);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Authenticating...");
        progressDialog.show();

        String email = _emailText.getText().toString();
        String password = _passwordText.getText().toString();

        Log.d(TAG, "login: "+email+"  "+password);
        // TODO: Implement your own authentication logic here.
        Call<LoginResponse> loginResponseCall = evidya.loginUser(Common.getHeaders(), email, password);

        loginResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                if(!response.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, ""+response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: fail "+response.code());
                    return;
                }

                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: success"+response.code()+"  "+response);

                if(response.body()!=null){
                    String content="";
//                    _loginButton.setEnabled(false);
                    LoginResponse loginResponse = response.body();
                    content += "code:"+ response.code();
                    content += "token:"+ loginResponse.getData().getAccessToken();
                    content += "result"+ loginResponse.getResult();
                    content += "result"+ loginResponse.getData().getDisplayName();
//                    onLoginSuccess();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: login res"+content);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Invalid response from server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Cannot fetch request", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
```

LoginResponse.java

```
package com.example.evidya.Retrofit.Model.LoginModel;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class LoginResponse {

    @SerializedName("result")
    @Expose
    private String result;
    @SerializedName("response_code")
    @Expose
    private Integer responseCode;
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private Data data;

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public Integer getResponseCode() {
        return responseCode;
    }

    public void setResponseCode(Integer responseCode) {
        this.responseCode = responseCode;
    }

    public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

Data.java

```
package com.example.evidya.Retrofit.Model.LoginModel;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Data {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("display_name")
    @Expose
    private String displayName;
    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    private String email;
    @SerializedName("username")
    @Expose
    private String username;
    @SerializedName("access_token")
    @Expose
    private String accessToken;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }

    public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getAccessToken() {
        return accessToken;
    }

    public void setAccessToken(String accessToken) {
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
    }

}
```

My Logging(ok hhttp), when clicking the login button with wrong details:

[image]

My Logging(ok hhttp), when clicking the login button with CORRECT details:

[image]
**Solution:**

Basically the problem  was that I was using                 `Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: success"+response.code()+"  "+response);` to check the response in the onresponse callback. Whereas all I should have done is to not get stuck there and check the value of the loginResponse object (from `LoginResponse loginResponse = response.body();`). Because response.body actually stores the reponse in object form. This is how things work in retrofit.

Comment: Add [HttpLoggingInterceptor](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-log-requests-and-responses) To validate the textual response . Also check logs for any parsing Error due to type .

Comment: as per base url, it seems like you are trying to call API from local network. Please confirm, if device is on local network or not.

Comment: Im calling the api, from my emulator, and getting status code as 200, also while signinp im having no problem

Comment: What makes you say this is related with parsing? Did you actually verify that you get a response, but failed to parse it? Could you add the logging interceptor like suggested and check it. Also, note that it's not up to Retrofit to parse the response. Retrofit is decoupled from this. People often use it together with gson and assume it's a one to one relationship, but it's not. You can use it for example with Moshi, which has superb error output.

Comment: @Fred I've added the okhttp logging that i get, pls check it, if you can find some error.One thing I have found just now is that response code is 200, which means a successful response, even though i put wrong information in the header, which should have generated "Authentication Error" message.

Comment: Ok, so seems like it's not a parsing issue, but something with the headers or parameters sent. Could you please paste here the call from postman with the exact parameters and headers? This will help us compare both and help you out understanding the issue.

Comment: @Fred please check the updated question, also it would help if you  go through my discussion with SamirBhatt in the answer section

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

As per your log, API calls properly. It also responds. but the issue is API authentication is failed from your back end. Add log on your web service and check. From the application side, it is working fine. this is not an issue of Retrofit.

Update your onResponse() with below and run application. then test and let me know what message you get.

```
if(response.body()!=null){
                LoginResponse loginResponse = response.body();
                String content="";
                if (response.body().getResponseCode()==200){
                    content+= loginResponse.getData().getAccessToken();
                    content+= loginResponse.getData().getDisplayName();
                    content+= loginResponse.getData().getEmail();
                    content+= loginResponse.getData().getId();
                    content+= loginResponse.getData().getUsername();
                }else{
                    content+=loginResponse.getData().getMsg();
                }

                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: login res"+content);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Invalid response from server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Below code in Data.java

```
 @SerializedName("msg")
        @Expose
        private String msg;
        public String getMsg() {
            return msg;
        }

        public void setMsg(String msg) {
            this.msg = msg;
        }
```

Comment: But why is the above red highlighted response is different from response.raw(or response) in the onResponse callback of Call.enque? Also you can check my updated response, when I enter the correct detalils

Comment: compare your request with the postman. also, check for header fields. When you check response.raw(), it will give you api call status which is 200. but failure is in your back-end. response.body() will give you actual response from API.

Comment: @Samir Bhatt Yes i've rechecked the header fields and in postman Im getting the desired response(see top of page), also in OkHttp logging, Im getting the desired response, which means problem should not be in the backend, but the response that I get in the onResponse callback is: {protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=http://192.168.0.52/evidya/wp-api/v1/user/login}, which is comlpletely different. ( I use LoginResponse loginResponse = response.body(); to parse the response)

Comment: in okhttp login, it is displaying {protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=192.168.0.52/evidya/wp-api/v1/user/login}, this is API response. that means API call is successful. Also, API gives response. but data which is send from back end is   : ["result":"failed",data : {msg : "Invalid Email or password."}]. You can add debug in API side and check for API issue.

Comment: As per your code you can check with  response.body().getResult() to check APIresonse status.

Comment: ["result":"failed",data : {msg : "Invalid Email or password."}] was the issue when I put the login credentials not im getting the desired response in OkHttp logging, which is not same as the one in onResponse Callback(in  loginResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
**Here***                }) . Please check the updated question

Comment: I also now checked reponse.body.getresult() which is success, still Im getting response as {protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=http://192.168.0.52/evidya/wp-api/v1/user/login}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191064/discussion-between-samir-bhatt-and-shikhar-jaiswal).

Comment: I don't know how but your condition        if (response.body().getResponseCode()==200){...} has finally solved the problem, because that is the only line I've added in my code. I would be glad if you could explain this, but still thanks a lot for your time and effort brother

Comment: if (response.body().getResponseCode()==200){...} this condition check response code of your API response. So, if API response is success full, it is 200[send from API response]  You are checking http response code. e.g. if user is not valid, in that case also, api call is successfull. So, it will give code 200